# How do I get the record types that are available to a user

Tags: rest-api, metadata, record-type

I'd like to retrieve the record types available for an object. Is the recommended way to do this to use the recordTypeInfos collection returned on the object's metadata?

Answer (score 5):

[Yes it is.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm)

> RecordTypeInfo Methods
> The following are methods for RecordTypeInfo.
> All are instance methods.
>
> - getName()  Returns the name of this record type.
> - getRecordTypeId() Returns the ID of this record type.
> - isAvailable()  Returns true if
>   this record type is available to the current user, false otherwise.
>   Use this method to display a list of available record types to the
>   user when he or she is creating a new record.
> - isDefaultRecordTypeMapping()  Returns true if this is the default
>   record type mapping, false otherwise.

Note that as it says, "is available" means the user can create new records with this type. It doesn't affect whether the users can see existing records of the type.